# I wish to upsert all the column values from my temp_table to master_table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

master_table:

| _id | zipcode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 100 |
| 456 | 200 |

temp_table:

| _id | zipcode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 111 |
| 245 | 222 |

master_table (new results must be upserted in master_table)

| _id | zipcode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | **111** |
| 456 | 200 |

my end goal is to insert records from temp_table to master_table and update existing records in master_table found in temp_table.

I have just given a sample table, It is not just the zipcode column which needs to be updated. there are many such columns (20+), all of them need to be updated.
just for a note : both the tables have same no. of columns.

Comment: How about a merge statement?

Answer (score 1):

Use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE master_table AS m
SET zipcode = t.zipcode
FROM temp_table t
WHERE m._id = t._id
```

Comment: I have just given a sample table, It is not just zipcode column which needs to be updated. there are many such columns (20+), all of them need to be updated.
just for a note : both the tables have same no. of columns.

Comment: ...then just add the correct number of assignments in the `SET` clause.

Comment: thank you for your response, this query works fine but it only updates the matching records from master_table with the new records present in temp_table. I also wish to add the records from the temp_table to master_table.

Comment: Then you need an upsert.  Your question does not say this,  by the way.

Comment: the question heading has upsert written. Could you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `WITH` to get data that need to be updated only.

This approach lets you develop and test your select query and in two steps convert it to the update query.

```
with t as (
  select m._id, t.zipcode as new_zipcode
  from master_table m
  inner join temp_table as t on t._id = m._id and t.zipcode <> m.zipcode
)
update master_table m
set zipcode = t.new_zipcode
from t
where m._id = t._id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uP-rMBMl)

To update multi columns just add them in `inner join`, and of course add them in the `SET` clause :

```
with t as (
  select m._id, t.zipcode, t.column2
  from master_table m
  inner join temp_table as t on t._id = m._id and ( t.zipcode <> m.zipcode or t.column2 <> m.column2)
)
update master_table m
set zipcode = t.zipcode, column2 = t.column2
from t
where m._id = t._id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/n7w9eyGI)

Comment: I have just given a sample table, It is not just zipcode column which needs to be updated. there are many such columns (20+), all of them need to be updated.
just for a note : both the tables have same no. of columns.